# Tremosine sul Garda, pronuncia corretta

Tags: pronunciation, accents, toponyms

L'unico [riferimento esplicito alla pronuncia (3⁰ paragrafo)](https://sognandoviaggi.wordpress.com/2016/07/07/la-romantica-tremosine-e-la-sua-terrazza-del-brivido/) di [Tremosine](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tremosine_sul_Garda) che abbia trovato da *Tremòsine*, sdrucciolo mentre di solito vedo scritto *Tremosine*, senza accento, verosimilmente piano...

Qual è la pronucia corretta?

PS, a colui che puote: non sarebbe utile il tag [toponym] (o [toponyms]) che per ora non esiste?

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Buona idea: procedo a creare la tag "toponyms".

Comment: Padova, Udine, Modena, Rimini, Bergamo, Genova, Ascoli, oltre a Napoli e Pesaro, sono alcuni capoluoghi di provincia con accento sulla terzultima sillaba.

Comment: Veramente, trovo complicato sapere quali parole italiane siano sdrucciole. Perlomeno io sbaglio spesso. Anche a volte mi trovo di aver inventato che un certo vocabolo è sdrucciolo quando veramente non lo è. Grazie al commento di @egreg ho appena scoperto che Udine è sdrucciola.

Comment: @Charo Al contrario, Friuli ha un dittongo ascendente: Friùli; la pronuncia con iato “Frìuli” è scorretta. Invece Nuoro ha iato: Nùoro. Nella lista vanno comprese Trapani, Cagliari e Sassari. Il castigliano ha regole ferree sull'accentazione, ma solo perché è da secoli la lingua di uno stato unitario che ha potuto imporle.

Comment: @egreg: Anche in catalano abbiamo tali norme e sono abbastanza recenti, basicamente sono di [Pompeu Fabra](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeu_Fabra). Infatti, ancora adesso si stanno facendo [modifiche di queste norme](https://www.elperiodico.cat/ca/societat/20160929/iec-retoca-ortografia-catala-5431893).

Comment: @Charo Sono evidentemente modellate sul castigliano, come quelle del portoghese. Il che non significa non siano utili! :-)

Comment: @egreg: Hai ragione, ma con alcune differenze importanti.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il [Dizionario d'ortografia e di pronunzia](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/) è utilissimo per questo tipo di dubbi. In particolare, [conferma la pronuncia con l'accento tonico sulla “o”](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=8064&r=250251) (e la “o” aperta) per Tremosine. Purtroppo il DOP non usa l'IPA come alfabeto fonetico: quella specie di “s” allungata denota la s “dolce” (cioè sonora).

Infine, non sempre l'assenza di accento grafico, anche in un toponimo, indica che la parola sia piana: pensa solo a Napoli o a Pesaro.

Comment: Vorrei accettare la risposta, ma devo aver fatto un pasticcio con la registrazione ed ora sono un Poldo diverso da quello che ha fatto la domanda — misteri di SE. Accontentati dell'upvote.  Circa "Napoli" e "Pesaro", scemo io :)

Comment: @PoldoSbaffini: Se vuoi unificare i tuoi account, nel "Help Center" si spiega quello che devi fare: "visit the [contact form](http://italian.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’."

Comment: Come bresciano, confermo: l'accento è sulla _o_, ed è pronunciata aperta. Difficilmente si troverà scritto con l'accento, ma c'è.

Comment: @charo, grazie per il suggerimento, ho unificato gli account e posso accettare la risposta!